# Javascript function after html appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my javascript function :

```
$(".like-btn").click(function () { .. }
```

this function is not triggered anymore after in my javascript somewhere else I do stuff like

```
 $("#1021").append("'<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default like-btn" ... .etc ");
```

So basically I need my jquery to be triggered also after I add some more html on my page.

Comment: See: [Understanding Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `like-btn` class is added dynamically, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler like this:

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$('#1021').on('click', '.like-btn', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('testlink'); 
});
```

Comment: The 1021 was just an example, the id changes :)

Comment: If the ID is changing that you provided for the example, you need to traverse up the DOM to the first static element available and use that as your selector. The above answer is correct, but you need to get the first parent element that isn't dynamic then.

Comment: Then you can use `document` instead. But, it would be better to use a parent static `container`. That would attach your event to any `like-btn` within the `container` element, reducing the scope of having to check the whole `document` element tree and increasing efficiency.